# Joining two metrics in promtheus and having all labels from both

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am polling F5 Pool and Node information from the snmp exporter and am managing to get the below metrics:

```
ltmPoolMbrStatusEnabledState{instance="ltm01", job="f5_ltm_test", ltmPoolMbrStatusEnabledState="1", ltmPoolMbrStatusNodeName="/Common/VPN1", ltmPoolMbrStatusPoolName="/Common/Pool1", ltmPoolMbrStatusPort="4500", prometheus="monitoring/k8s", prometheus_replica="prometheus-k8s-0"}

ltmPoolMbrStatusAvailState{instance="ltm01", job="f5_ltm_test", ltmPoolMbrStatusAvailState="2", ltmPoolMbrStatusNodeName="/Common/VPN1", ltmPoolMbrStatusPoolName="/Common/Pool1", ltmPoolMbrStatusPort="4500", prometheus="monitoring/k8s", prometheus_replica="prometheus-k8s-0"}
```

However, would like to join the metrics together to get something like:

```
ltmPoolMbrStatusState{instance="ltm01", job="f5_ltm_test", ltmPoolMbrStatusEnabledState="1", ltmPoolMbrStatusAvailState="2", ltmPoolMbrStatusNodeName="/Common/VPN1", ltmPoolMbrStatusPoolName="/Common/Pool1", ltmPoolMbrStatusPort="4500", prometheus="monitoring/k8s", prometheus_replica="prometheus-k8s-0"}
```

Noting that `ltmPoolMbrStatusEnabledState` and `ltmPoolMbrStatusAvailState` occur in the final metric.

Is there a way to do this within the scrape job relabelling bits or does this have to be done with a query?

If so please could someone assist with the query I would need to join the two metrics. The common labels are `instance, ltmPoolMbrStatusNodeName, ltmPoolMbrStatusPoolName and ltmPoolMbrStatusPort`.

I have tried doing a join but it only seems to bring in one of the `ltmPoolMbrStatusEnabledState` and `ltmPoolMbrStatusAvailState` metrics depending on if its a left or right join, but I would like both to appear.

Thanks in advance.